# org-babel pass bibtex sample to python code block

Tags: org-babel, python, bibtex

Is it possible to pass a sample `bibtex` document into a python source code block to be evaluated?

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       d7154890-6d45-44c0-9b0c-9c0f6533c11e
:header-args: :session bibtex
:END:

#+NAME: sample_bib
#+BEGIN_SRC bibtex
@book{崔光宙_先秦儒家禮樂敎化思想在現代敎育上的涵義與實施_1985,
  title = {先秦儒家禮樂敎化思想在現代敎育上的涵義與實施},
  author = {{崔光宙}},
  date = {1985},
  series = {私立東吳大學中國學術著作獎助委員會叢書},
  edition = {初版},
  number = {94},
  publisher = {{私立東吳大學中國學術著作獎助委員會}},
  location = {{台北市}},
  langid = {chi}
}

@article{李平_中國古代樂論的易學淵源_1996,
  title = {中國古代樂論的《易》學淵源},
  author = {{李平}},
  date = {1996},
  journaltitle = {音樂藝術.上海音樂學院學報},
  number = {01},
  pages = {11-16+27},
  issn = {1000-4270},
  url = {https://kns.cnki.net/kcms/detail/detail.aspx?dbcode=CJFD&dbname=CJFD9697&filename=SHYB199601002&v=IRe2C4LIBXc2dm%25mmd2FCtYiLuYcL8BGh6BOP9B5FiG59mEXb4llLOFZuq17u9CBg6yGt},
  urldate = {2021-07-26},
  langid = {中文;},
  keywords = {《乐论》,《周易》,《易》,《易》学,十二律,吕氏春秋,天地万物,音乐本体}
#+END_SRC



#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :noweb yes
import bibtexparser
from bibtexparser.bwriter import BibTexWriter
from bibtexparser.bibdatabase import BibDatabase

with open(<<sample_bib>>) as bibtex_file:
    bibtex_str = bibtex_file.read()

    db = bibtexparser.loads(bibtex_str)

print(db)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

The python source block above returns no results. And there is `No org-babel-execute` function for bibtex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple bibtex execute function like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun org-babel-execute:bibtex (body params)
  body)
#+END_SRC
```

Then use a variable instead of noweb like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :var bibdata=sample_bib
import bibtexparser
from bibtexparser.bwriter import BibTexWriter
from bibtexparser.bibdatabase import BibDatabase

db = bibtexparser.loads(bibdata)

print(db)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: <bibtexparser.bibdatabase.BibDatabase object at 0x7f87201f8910>
```